# Fixing delimiters to align with beginning of new line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, citing, multiple-citations

Spaces seem to be not dropped at newlines with biblatex.

MWE (to be used with the `references.bib` file linked to below):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=ynt,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false,backref=true,dashed=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib} %Location of references.bib only for biblatex, Do not omit the .bib extension from the filename.

\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{ and }
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}



\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{}%\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
\noindent
for $w\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $w\geq 0$ may be used in most  conference schemes~\parencite{neal11,kucukelbir17,ranganath14}. If the number of nonzero entries $\|w\|_0$ of $w$ is small, this results in a significant reduction in computational burden.
\end{document}
```

Output (note the extra space at the end of the first line; the semicolon should be flush with the end of line.)

[image]

Please find files at
[test.tex](https://github.com/dionman/thesis/blob/master/test.tex). Files [cls](https://github.com/dionman/thesis/blob/master/Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls) and [citations](https://github.com/dionman/thesis/blob/master/References/references.bib) are also required

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add an example showing the issue? In general, spaces are removed when they follow a line break.

Comment: just posting fragments makes it harder to debug, can you post a small complete test file that shows the problem

Comment: Please do a better job trimming your MWE. Pretty much nothing in the `cls` file is needed. And you can trim the references file to only the three sample bibliography entries. (You have multiple dozens.)

Comment: I trimmed your MWE to something that is more or less minimal. Note that if you replace `\multicitedelim` by `;` in the definitions of `\cite` and `\parencite` the extra space goes away.

Comment: that's wonderful, thanks!